# Conditionally dividing rows from two different data frames in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I currently have two tables, `endingStock` and `totalUsage`, with each row in each table having a date entry. I want to iterate over the rows of each table, compare the date, and if the dates are the same, I want to extract the value of a variable `unit value` from both endingStock and totalUsage, and append `endingstock$unitvalue / totalUsage$unitvalue` to a third table, `ratioTable`.

Using a bunch of different answers on this site, I've tried setting `ratioTable` to `NULL` and building up the table row by row, using the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(endingStocks)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(useTotals)) {
    if (endingStocks[i,]$valuedate == useTotals[j,]$valuedate) {
      ratio = endingStocks[i,]$`unit value` / useTotals[j,]$`unit value`
      newrow <- c(endingStocks[i,]$valuedate, ratio)
      ratioTable <- rbind(ratioTable, newrow)
    }
  }
}
```

However, this seems to be skipping values. Each dataframe has over 200 entries that are roughly matched in terms of date, and so the resultant `ratioTable` should have the same order of entries, but instead only has 24.

1) Is there a way to effectively do this using vectorized operations?

2) Are there any glaring faults with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing without a reproducible example, but I think using merge will do what you want:

```
ratioTable = merge(endingStocks, totalUsage, by="valuedate")
```

You can then tidy your new table as required.